# Hover dropdown not working in JavaScript: it doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code is not working. The menus aren't dropping down on hover. What is supposed to be wrong in the code?
It only displays the word 'Action' and when I hover on it, it doesn't show anything.

```js
$("#hoverli").hover(
  function() {
    $('#actions_menu').finish().slideDown('fast');
  },
  function() {
    $('#actions_menu').finish().slideUp('fast');
  }
);
```

```css
.lbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: silver;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* dark navy blue */
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 11pt;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.divMenuWrapper1 {
  height: 25px;
  width: 75px;
}

.file_menu {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100000;
}

.file_menu div {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.file_menu div a {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.file_menu div a:hover {
  padding: 3px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="divMenuWrapper1" class="divMenuWrapper1">
    <div id="hoverli">
      <div class="lbtn">
        Actions
      </div>
      <div id="actions_menu" class="file_menu">
        <div><a href="#file">File</a></div>
        <div><a href="#edit">Edit</a></div>
        <div><a href="#view">View</a></div>
        <hr />
        <div><a href="#insert">Insert</a></div>
        <div><a href="#modify">Modify</a></div>
        <div><a href="#control">Control</a></div>
        <div><a href="#debug">Debug</a></div>
        <div><a href="#window">Window</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

P.S. I tried to run it in Snippet and Fiddle and yes it's working however when I run it in my PC it is definitely not working. And I'm using the same code.

Comment: You just need to add link of JQuery.js to your html code

Comment: Check your browser's console for errors. I'd guess that your jQuery code is running before the page content is available, explaining why the snippet works but your version doesn't.

Comment: @Chiller what do you mean add a link? i dont understand. I wasnt using external js. Its embedded in the html and im using .html as format. Is it wrong?

Comment: @AndyG i checked. It says $ is not defined. What to do for it to get defined?

Comment: Make sure jQuery is loaded before your own code runs. Your code relies on jQuery ($) being loaded.

Comment: @KatieSerenVera you are using JQuery in your javascript, so you need to load it first ...`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` add this before your embedded code.

Comment: @Chiller i already added it but it still wont work.

Comment: @KatieSerenVera edit your question and add the your code as is without making a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code in working state. You need to make sure you have imported jQuery before your snippet.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="divMenuWrapper1" class="divMenuWrapper1">
    <div id="hoverli">
      <div class="lbtn">
        Actions
      </div>
      <div id="actions_menu" class="file_menu">
        <div><a href="#file">File</a></div>
        <div><a href="#edit">Edit</a></div>
        <div><a href="#view">View</a></div>
        <hr />
        <div><a href="#insert">Insert</a></div>
        <div><a href="#modify">Modify</a></div>
        <div><a href="#control">Control</a></div>
        <div><a href="#debug">Debug</a></div>
        <div><a href="#window">Window</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<style>
.lbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: silver;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* dark navy blue */
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 11pt;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.divMenuWrapper1 {
  height: 25px;
  width: 75px;
}

.file_menu {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100000;
}

.file_menu div {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.file_menu div a {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.file_menu div a:hover {
  padding: 3px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hoverli").hover(
    function() {
        $('#actions_menu').finish().slideDown('fast');
    },
    function() {
        $('#actions_menu').finish().slideUp('fast');
    }
  );
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you! its working now. Why do i need the jquery tho if i am using javascript? I need to understand those two!

Comment: This:

`$("#hoverli").hover(
    function() {
        $('#actions_menu').finish().slideDown('fast');
    },
    function() {
        $('#actions_menu').finish().slideUp('fast');
    }
  );`

is a jQuery code. Thus, you need jQuery. Else, you need to convert it to  JavaScript equivalent snippet.

Comment: I see. I dont understand the difference in  coding. It looks the same to me. Anyways, is there a javascript equivalent code to it? I really thought it was JS code. What is the equivalent code? May i know so that i can see the difference between them?

Comment: `$("#hoverli")` is `document.getElementById('hoverli')` in JavaScript. Also, there isn't any `hover()` event in JavaScript. It can be achieved by handling other mouse events. Also, this particular code is a bit too complex to achieve in JavaScript.

Comment: There really is a difference. Thank you for telling me.